# Reading from JSONP

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I have the following script which is able to access a jsonp feed and get data from it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    get_jsonp_feed();

    function get_jsonp_feed() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%20SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fnews.bbc.co.uk%2Fweather%2Fforecast%2F4276%3Fsearch%3Dgerrards%2520cross%26itemsPerPage%3D10%26region%3Dworld%26area%3DGerrards%2520Cross%22%20and%20xpath%20%3D%20'%2F%2Ftable%2Ftbody%2Ftr'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=cbfunc",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            jsonpCallback: 'cbfunc',
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            },
            success: function(data) { 
                var itemList = data.query;

                alert(itemList.count);

                /*
                var buildHTML = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    buildHTML.push('<div class="container"><a href="' + itemList[i].link + '" class="title" target="_blank">' + itemList[i].title + '<br /><span class="dateandtime">' + itemList[i].pubDate + '</span></a></div>');
                }

                $('.portlet-content').empty().append(buildHTML.join('<hr />'))
                */
            }
        });
    }
});
```

That gives me `5` which is right.  I now want to get data which is more embedded in the jsonp, but I have having difficulty.  For example, I want to get:

```
data.query.results.tr.td.div.abbr.title
```

How would I go about getting that?

Here is a jsfiddle of it returning 5:
http://jsfiddle.net/B6hRG/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some fixed code to get JSONP instead of XML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    get_jsonp_feed();

    function get_jsonp_feed() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%20%3D%20'http%3A%2F%2Fnews.bbc.co.uk%2Fweather%2Fforecast%2F4276%3F%26search%3Dgerrards%2520cross%26itemsPerPage%3D10%26region%3Dworld%26area%3DGerrards%2520Cross'%20and%20xpath%20%3D%20'%2F%2Ftbody%2Ftr'&format=json&callback=?",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var itemList = data.query;

                alert(itemList.count);

                /*
                var buildHTML = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    buildHTML.push('<div class="container"><a href="' + itemList[i].link + '" class="title" target="_blank">' + itemList[i].title + '<br /><span class="dateandtime">' + itemList[i].pubDate + '</span></a></div>');
                }

                $('.portlet-content').empty().append(buildHTML.join('<hr />'))
                */
            }
        });
    }
});
```

To get data like `data.query.results.tr.td.div.abbr.title` you'd have to either use a `for` loop on the `data.query.results.tr.td` object, and any others with siblings, or use XML and get the raw html, put it into a document fragment and use jQuery on that.

Comment: I've updated the original question to get jsonp instead of xml.